# (macos terminal) Changing the first letter of a regex match to uppercase

Tags: macos, sed

OK, I'll explain with an example:

```
echo "x,y (fifo(x,y) , q(x) , fifo(z))" | sed 's/f\([a-z]*\)/F\1/g'

output: x,y (Fifo(x,y) , q(x) , Fifo(z))
```

So basically I want to match on every word (letters only) that ends with a "(", and change the first letter of that word to uppercase.
My code doesn't really work because I'd like "q(x)" to become "Q(x)" too.

In my example I do this manually by specifing "f" and "F" in the sed command (which means that it doesn't work for "q(x)") - is there a way to do this without repeating the same command for every letter in the alphabet?

GNU sed seems to have a way of making a letter uppercase, but I don't think it's supported on mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed for `\u` to convert the next letter to upper case:

```
$ echo "x,y (fifo(x,y) , q(x) , fifo(z))" | sed -E 's/(\w)(\w*\()/\u\1\2/g'
x,y (Fifo(x,y) , Q(x) , Fifo(z))
```

You can install GNU sed on macOS. Othewrise with any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    head = ""
    while ( match($0,/[[:alpha:]]+\(/) ) {
        head = head substr($0,1,RSTART-1) toupper(substr($0,RSTART,1)) substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head $0
}

$ echo "x,y (fifo(x,y) , q(x) , fifo(z))" | awk -f tst.awk
x,y (Fifo(x,y) , Q(x) , Fifo(z))
```

Comment: I've never used awk, I guess it's finally time to learn it. Thank you!

Comment: Great awk solution Ed... Why the double `[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]` in the regexp, when a single `[[:alpha:]]` seems to achieve the same result ? Does double address a particular edge case?

Comment: Originally I was going to match `[[:lower:]][[:alpha:]]*` then changed lower to alpha too and didn't update the whole thing to just `[[:alpha:]]+`. I updated it now.

Comment: @EdMorton Does every `awk` edition support `+` in regex? I thought `aa*` to emmulate `a+` was actually a good practice :)

Comment: @Tiw yes, all awks only support EREs, it's all seds and greps that support BREs by default and some support EREs with `-E/-r` args or backslashes before the ERE chars. So you can always use `a+` in awk, while in sed and grep you need `aa*` for portability but in some versions (e.g. GNU) can use `a+` with `-E` (or `-r` in older GNU sed) or `a\+` without `-E`

Answer (score 2):

It's not impossible but it's a quite hard thing for the `sed` on macos to do it.
Why not change to use `ruby` instead?(afaik `ruby` is preinstalled on macos, right?)
Try this:

```
echo "x,y (fIfo(x,y) , q(x) , fifo(z))" | ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/([a-z]+)(?=\()/i){$1.capitalize}'
```

Output:

```
x,y (Fifo(x,y) , Q(x) , Fifo(z))
```

Notice I changed to `fIfo` in the echo, and used `i` flag to ruby's regex for case**i**nsensitve.

Comment: thanks, if it's hard to do with sed on macos, I guess I might try using a bash loop - but thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @cmscalzo Another choice: Just install GNU sed, and use it instead :)

Comment: wrt `I might try using a bash loop` - no, don't do that. bash is a shell. a shell is designed to call tools to perform tasks with a language to sequence those calls. It's not designed to manipulate text - the people who invented shell invented other tools for shell to call to manipulate text including awk for any general purpose text manipulation. So if you need to do more text manipulation than `g/re/p` (`grep`) or `s/old/new/` (`sed`) then do it in awk, not shell.

Comment: @cmscalzo you might find https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/133219 interesting reading.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, figured out a `macOS sed` solution, the mechanism is to use a loop to *switch pattern to line beginning, and uppercase first letter, then switch back.*(using `\r` to separate)
 It will be too long so I'll skip to transfer it to a one-liner.
Also it only uppercase first letter in pattern, won't lowercase following letters, so it's not strictly speaking a *capitalize* function. However using similar mechanism it can be done.

```
echo "x,y (fifo(x,y) , q(x) , fifo(z))" | sed -e '
/^[a-z][a-z]*(/breplace
:circle
/[^a-zA-Z][a-z][a-z]*(/!bend
s/\(.*[^a-zA-Z]\)\([a-z][a-z]*(.*\)/\2\r\1/
:replace
s/^a/A/
s/^b/B/
s/^c/C/
s/^d/D/
s/^e/E/
s/^f/F/
s/^g/G/
s/^h/H/
s/^i/I/
s/^j/J/
s/^k/K/
s/^l/L/
s/^m/M/
s/^n/N/
s/^o/O/
s/^p/P/
s/^q/Q/
s/^r/R/
s/^s/S/
s/^t/T/
s/^u/U/
s/^v/V/
s/^w/W/
s/^x/X/
s/^y/Y/
s/^z/Z/
/\r/s/\(.*\)\r\(.*\)/\2\1/
bcircle
:end
'
```

Output:

```
x,y (Fifo(x,y) , Q(x) , Fifo(z))
```

If anyone wondering, I didn't type those `s`es manually,
I use `awk 'BEGIN{for(i=97;i<123;i++)printf "s/^%c/%c/\n", i, i-32}'` created them.

Comment: Nice! Would you mind explaining the breplace, circle, etc.? I have never seen them before.

Comment: @cmscalzo `b`/`/t` are like `goto`s (`t` is conditional, `b` unconditional), and letters after are destination corresponding to `:label`s.

Comment: @cmscalzo Actually I should all use `b` in this snippet, just updated. You can refer to this GNU sed's document about [flow-control](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Branching-and-flow-control.html). GNU sed has more functionalities, but the basic ones are the same.